# ARDUINO tweet many times

Tags: twitter

I want to tweet corresponding to a situation which means I need to tweet many times. I did like this:

```
void loop() {
    checkState();
}

void tweet() {
    Serial.println("Connecting to Twitter");
    if (twitter.post("input is greater than 5")) {
        Serial.print(dataString);
        int status = twitter.wait();
        if (status == 200) {
            Serial.println("Successful");
        } else {
            Serial.println("Tweet failed.");
            Serial.println(status);
        }
    } else {
        Serial.println("Connection to Twitter failed");
    }
    Serial.println("30 Seconds timeout started");
    delay(3000);
}

void checkState() {
    // read input and append to the string:
    char analogPin = 0;
    char input = analogRead(analogPin);
    dataString = input;
    if (input >= 1023) {
        tweet();
        delay(2000);
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: `delay(3000);` it's 3 seconds, not 30.

Comment: @DomenicoLeoneLuciani you are right. So do you have any idea what is wrong other than this?